# Aside from this two practical technique to compute any integral, what else?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Aside from this two practical technique to compute any integral, what else could called a fundamental method but not approximate method like Riemann Sum?

These two method I've been referring to are called integration by parts, integration by substitution(changing of variables)

Comment: Use of an integration table. :D

Comment: I think integrating the hypergeometric representation with tables of rules is my favorite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call these two methods particularly *fundamental*. The way I see it, there are two basic ways to compute an integral

1. Computing it directly from the *definition* of the integral, i.e. as some kind of limit.
2. Using properties of the integral to  reduce the integral in question to one that is already known.

There are lots of ways to accomplish (2), and integration by parts and substitution are merely two well-known ones. Other that come to mind are

1. Differentiating under the integral sign
2. Swapping the integration order. For originally one-dimensional integrals, the first step is to somehow interpret them as a multi-dimensional one. In particular, this technique works to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^{-2}}$.
3. Contour integration. Here, one basically reduces an integral to a sum of of integrals of $\frac{c}{z}$ along closed paths around $0$.

But there surely are many others.

Answer (score 4):

Some helpful links:

http://www.intmath.com/methods-integration/methods-integration-intro.php

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntTechIntro.aspx

Paul's Online Notes are the best for learning calculus :)